# My "Delete Comment" function from my Ruby on Rails Blog Website doesn't work and I don't know why

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

My "Delete Comment" function from my Ruby on Rails Blog Website doesn't work and I don't know why.

Here is my error:

Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/posts/17/comments/9"
Rails.root: C:/Sites/blog
Routes
Routes match in priority from top to bottom

"comments_controller.rb" file:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))

    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
end
```

"_comment.html.erb":

```
<div class="comment clearfix">
<div class="comment_content">
    <p class="comment_name"><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
    <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
    <p class="comment_time"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> Ago</p>
</div>

<p>
    <%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.post, comment],
                method: :detele,
                class: "button",
                data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} 
    %>
</p>
</div>
```

"_form.html.erb":

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>

<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name %><br>

<br>
<%= f.label :body %><br>
<%= f.text_area :body %><br>

<br>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

"show.html.erb":

```
<div id="post_content">
<h1 class="title">
    <%= @post.title %>
</h1>

<p class="date">
    Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> Ago
    | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
    | <%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(@post),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>

<p class="body">
    <%= @post.body %>
</p>

<div id="comment">
    <h2><%= @post.comments.count %> Comments </h2>
    <%= render @post.comments %>

    <h3>Add a comment: </h3>
    <%= render "comments/form" %>
</div>
</div>
```

"posts.rb":

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
validates :title, presence: true
validates :body, presence: true
end
```

"routes.rb":

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :posts do 
    resources :comments
end

root "posts#index"
end
```

I really don't know how to fix this. Please help me. Thank you! <3

Comment: Add the stacktrace you get when making the request to delete the resource.

Comment: Sorry but I am a beginner. How can I do that? And what is a stacktrace?

Comment: At the moment of performing the request, go to your rails server and copy and paste the content that output in your question.

Comment: not sure if this was a typo from copy / paste but ‘delete’ is misspelled in `method: :detele` in your _comment.html.erb partial

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works! <3